# Suggestions on How to Remove Very Old Carpet Tape from Hardwood Floor

Tags: hardwood-floor, carpet

The tape was double-sided mesh carpet tape. It has been under a runner in an entryway for about 20 years and is now just a dried mesh and whatever residue is left from the glue that was on the tape.  Can anyone suggest a method of removing the tape without doing damage to the floor?  Thanks!

Comment: isopropanol (not rubbing alcohol, because that contains oil) .....  orange cleaner (made from oranges)  ..... test on small area of floor first

Comment: @jsotola Sounds like an answer I would vote for.

Comment: can you add a photo so we can teeter on the "it's dry and crusty" "or gooey and messy" side of "old"

Comment: I will do that as soon as I get home this evening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A heat gun warm up the yape it will get sticky again and pull it off then the stick stuff from the tape 90 per cent alcohol will take it off and your floor is not damaged

Answer (score 1):

A plastic putty knife can often remove residue if it isn't too sticky. In a pinch, an old plastic credit card can also work. If the surface finish is weak, it may lift with the residue.

Answer (score 1):

Soaking the tape in WD-40 may be able to dissolve the glue and make it easier to remove. You may have to leave it for a few hours to soak in considering the age of the material.

Comment: Thanks Karl.  In the end I used a heat gun to remove most of the tape, worked like a charm, then a cloth with alcohol to tidy up.

Answer (score -1):

Use a carburetor cleaner like Chemtool; spray, let sit for a minute, pull off.

Comment: I don't know enough about carb cleaner to know - are you sure this won't destroy the finish on a hardwood floor?

Comment: Carb cleaner is basically acetone.

Comment: In that case, yes, it will dissolve some finishes.

Comment: I did not vote to delete because I  am not sure.  Its not a good one, but it is an answer. Perhaps downvote is the correct action for it.

Comment: @RohitGupta Agree. Where's your d/v?